# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using React.lazy to load some React classes on runtime so that they are not all loaded at once. My code works for production, but crashes when I am in development mode. **(UPDATE: My code no longer works in production - see below).**

The particular error message is very cryptic so hard to know exactly what the issue is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ (main.js:64)

The above error occurred in one of your React components:
    in Unknown
    in Suspense
    in div (created by Main)
    in Main (created by Route)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ (main.js:64)
```

Line 64 gives the following code:

```
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

I have other React classes that are not having any issues.

The particular class file that I created is called Categories.js. As far as I know I am not loading the class any differently than any of the ones that are working. I have even tried renaming the class/file and have I have also removed most of my data out of it in case something in the file was causing the issue.

Here are the pertinent lines from my code:

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
....
const Categories = React.lazy(()=> import('./Categories'))
....
return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Categories class_select={class_select} />
    </Suspense>
 )
```

If it helps here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {

  const isProduction = (argv.mode === "production")
  return {

          module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: "babel-loader",
                  options: {
                    plugins: [
                        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: "html-loader"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          ...(isProduction && {
                  optimization: {
                   // minimize: true,
                    minimizer: [
                        new TerserPlugin({
                                terserOptions: {
                                        extractComments: 'all',
                                        compress: {
                                                drop_console: true
                                        },

                                }
                        })
                    ],
                  }
          }),
          devtool: !isProduction && 'eval-source-map',
          plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
              template: "./src/index.html",
              filename: "./index.html"
            }),
            new CopyPlugin([
              { from: 'src/css', to: 'css' }
            ])
          ]
     };
};
```

**Questions**

1) What is causing this error?
2) Why is it only being caused in dev mode but not production mode?

**Update**

My code no longer works in production either. I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at o (main.js:2).
```

In fact it is even worse in production than dev. In production none of the React lazy classes are working. In dev it is only one of them that isn't working.

Comment: I don't know how far you got on solving this issue, I am on my side trying to find a solution. One of the cause seems to be tied to optimization of the code. If I understood right there are [issues of naming between the JS files when the package is built](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8996#issuecomment-479777461) which cause some files to lose the reference to modules, hence the "undefined" issues. I'm still working on it, if I find a solution I'll come back to your question.

Answer (score 26):

### Process

In order to find a potential solution to this issue, I had to tinker with the optimization module, which was indeed the issue here, even when not enabled surprisingly.
My best guess is that some parameters are set to default in `production` mode and not in `dev` mode and this causes the issues of imports and undefined properties.

I decided to try **replicating the deployment environment and check if I could at least "break" the development** as well and investigate the issue from here. These are the parameters that are different between production and development and that were suspect in causing the issue at hand (you can try yourself by switching to the opposite value to put your `deployment` like the `development` environment for example).

On the [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8996#issuecomment-479777461) I provided in the comment, the user was explaining that the issue was at deployment level and that the way the `vendors` chunk were built, were colliding with the `main` chunks and cuts the `entry` to one another. One of the solution was to use `concatenateModules: false` apparently, but to no avail, it didn't solve my issue. So I tried with the others and found the issue bellow.

### Potential solution

in `module.exports`, the `optimization` object should be edited

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    namedModules: true,
    namedChunks: true,
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    flagIncludedChunks: true,
    occurrenceOrder: false,
    usedExports: true,
    concatenateModules: true,
    sideEffects: false, // <----- in prod defaults to true if left blank
}
```

*Edit: all of these parameters are set to their opposite between production and development, tweak them at your own leisure, some issues stems from them*

### Explanation

After switching all the parameters I found that the `sideEffects` one is the one that breaks things and I see why:

The [sideEffects flag](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationsideeffects) will break down imports into separate ones as follow, as per the [documentation on sideEffects](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/side-effects/README.md):

```
import { a, b } from "big-module-with-flag"
```

is rewritten to

```
import { a } from "big-module-with-flag/a";
import { b } from "big-module-with-flag/b";
```

And will try to optimize imports accordingly across the modules, which can cause issues in production. Normally this should help optimizing the size of the package by reducing the bundles, at the cost of removing some imports but can break things at import.

*I hope the explanation was somewhat clear, if somebody has deeper knowledge on WebPack optimization, any documentation and enhancement would be welcome.*

Comment: Also thought it was the `sideEffects` flag, what helped in my case was upgrading my `v4` `webpack` from `4.12` to `latest` (`4.45`), minimal helpful version was `4.30` (fixed https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8916, which has something to do with `chunks`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting the full `optimizations` object with all of its options switched to the opposite value! Bisecting this list just saved me a couple hours of investigation of my very specific issue.

Comment: I ran into this issue when trying to add the `dompurify` package and tried various things including updating versions of babel, webpack to latest 4.46, and even trying alternative packages such as `sanitize-html`. Ultimately setting `optimizations.sideEffects` to `false` is what did it for this case. Thanks for digging into this and posting the solution @Pierre-Chevallier!

Comment: I still can't believe this error is still occurring, it has been more than 3 years since I posted this answer! @jpierson

Comment: I take back my comment.  By making this change it did help but the fix was somewhat inconsistent still. When I looked into it further the root cause had to do with the platform that I was working with limiting the size of assets which were updated and served to the user (unfortunately with a quite mundane warning logged as the only indication). Changing the webpack optimizations did help however to tease this out as it had an effect on the size of those assets which put it right under the threshold in my case.

Comment: @PierreChevallier thanks so much! works for me, my issue was with re-pack and module federation!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error, extremely difficult to diagnose the root cause from a minified JavaScript stack trace. In the end, I just **upgraded the Webpack version** to the latest 4.X stable release (I was using Angular 11, so no Webpack 5 support) and the problem magically went away. Assume there must have been some dependency tree bug in the Webpack 4.2.X version that I was using previously.

Webpack versions reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack

Commands

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack@4.46.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error that would only occur on production.
Production had Cloudflare but Test did not.
It turned out our Cloudflare cache settings were ignoring our cache busting. Cache busting via query parameters `/scripts/main.js?v=1080237476`. So our code-split Webpack output had mis-matched JavaScript files and threw the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`.
The quick fix was to purge our Cloudflare cache after deploy. Long term fix is to configure our Cloudflare settings or use hashed filenames instead of query parameters for cache busting.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was with the "splitChunks" property of the optimization object. Removing that property solved the problem.

Before:

```
optimization: {
minimize: true,
minimizer: [new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(), '...'],
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all',
},
}
```

After:

```
optimization: {
minimize: true,
minimizer: [new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(), '...'],
},
```