# Create React App production build runtime error: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a CRA project that runs fine when i use `react-scripts start` in development.   But once I build `react-scripts build` and then serve these files, I get this error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`
[image]

I dont have any custom webpack config.   I've tried to comment large areas of source code, and I still get this error trying to serve the build files.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: share your code

Comment: Its a bit long to share.
https://github.com/barrard/stock_panel

Comment: Checking the code!!!

Comment: I even just pushed up the source code all commented out
And still see this error, I must have some cache error or something?

Comment: If you can add one line like `config.optimization.minimize  = false` in webpack.config.js to disable the obfuscating function, it should very helpful for debugging, though from your screenshot I am not able to point out whether it is a logic problem or syntax problem.

Comment: Im a little bit new to CRA and webpack config.  Do I need to eject the app or just create the .config file and it all works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this answer, and it solved the issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628185/5231665
I just had to add this to the `react-scripts` `webpack.config.js`

```
optimization: {
    sideEffects: false,// <----- in production defaults to true if left blank
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barrard's solution worked for me.

If you're building a Create React App and don't want to eject the application, the following steps are how I updated my webpack config:

1. Add `customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired` [0]
2. Update your `start` and `build` scripts to use `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts` [1]
3. There is no built in API to update the `optimization.sideEffects` property, so we have to build our own [2]. Create a `config-overrides.js` file where your `package.json` is and add the following code in there:

```
const { override } = require("customize-cra");

const setOptimizationSideEffect = flag => config => {
    config.optimization.sideEffects = flag
    return config;
}

module.exports = override(
    setOptimizationSideEffect(false)
);
```

---

[0] https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra

[1] https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#3-flip-the-existing-calls-to-react-scripts-in-npm-scripts-for-start-build-and-test

[2] https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/issues/155#issuecomment-523958656