# WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/sockjs-node' failed:

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, micro-frontend

I am working in a react application (Below **Package.json**)

```
{
  "name": "seed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^23.5.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^23.5.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "3.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-real-time-collaboration": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "23.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "23.1.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.1.5",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.22",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "env-cmd": "8.0.2",
    "formik": "2.1.5",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "juice": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "pdf-viewer-reactjs": "^2.0.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.4.456",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-hot-toast": "^1.0.2",
    "react-intl": "2.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router": "4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.20",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "styled-components": "4.1.1",
    "superagent": "4.0.0",
    "typesafe-actions": "^3.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true REACT_APP_ENV=local react-app-rewired start",
    "start:windows": "set HTTPS=true&&set REACT_APP_ENV=local&&react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "env-cmd .env.${REACT_APP_ENV} react-app-rewired build",
    "build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging env-cmd .env.staging react-app-rewired build ",
    "build:qa": "REACT_APP_ENV=qa env-cmd .env.qa react-app-rewired build ",
    "build:qaint": "REACT_APP_ENV=qaint env-cmd .env.qaint react-app-rewired build ",
    "build:euat": "REACT_APP_ENV=euat env-cmd .env.euat react-app-rewired build ",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --maxWorkers=4",
    "test:ci": "react-app-rewired test --maxWorkers=4 --all --coverage",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "analyze": "env-cmd .env.${REACT_APP_ENV} react-app-rewired build --analyze-bundle",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage",
    "generate": "plop --plopfile scripts/generators/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "lint:fix": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --fix",
    "lint-style": "stylelint 'src/**/*.style.{ts,tsx}' 'src/**/style.{ts,tsx}'",
    "cypress:run": "sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-cypress.yml run e2e-chrome"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie < 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!src/**/*.test.js",
      "!src/**/actions.js",
      "!src/**/index.js",
      "!src/**/serviceWorker.js",
      "!src/**/*.wrap.js",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/tempPolyfills.js",
      "!src/setupTests.js",
      "!src/redux/reducers.js",
      "!src/redux/sagas.js",
      "!src/redux/store.js",
      "!src/**/mocks/**",
      "!src/redux/reducers.ts",
      "!src/redux/sagas.ts"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 0,
        "branches": 0,
        "functions": 0,
        "lines": 0
      }
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "bundlesize": [
    {
      "path": "./build/static/js/*.js",
      "maxSize": "200 kB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.10",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
    "@types/enzyme-react-intl": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.2",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.12",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/pdf-viewer-reactjs": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-intl": "^2.3.15",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.12",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.5",
    "@types/superagent": "^3.8.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.34",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.8.0",
    "enzyme": "3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15",
    "enzyme-react-intl": "^2.0.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-mysticatea": "4.2.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-object-spread": "1.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.2",
    "plop": "2.1.0",
    "prettier": "1.15.1",
    "react-app-rewire-webpack-bundle-analyzer": "1.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "2.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.10",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-declaration-strict-value": "^1.1.2",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.5.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "wait-on": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Below **config-overrides.js**

```
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );

module.exports = {
  webpack: function override(config, env) {
    const analyzeBundle = process.argv.indexOf('--analyze-bundle') !== -1;

    if (analyzeBundle) {
      const rewireWebpackBundleAnalyzer = require('react-app-rewire-webpack-bundle-analyzer');
      config = rewireWebpackBundleAnalyzer(config, env, {
        analyzerMode: 'static',
        reportFilename: 'report.html',
      });
    }

    // Fix strange issue with webpack build
    // details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407393/create-react-app-production-build-runtime-error-cannot-read-property-call-of
    // TODO: maybe update webpack to fix while keeping import optimization
    config.optimization.sideEffects = false;
    // Customize webpack config here
    console.log("Loading Custom config for Webpack, rebuilding ckeditor");
    const oneOfIndex = config.module.rules.findIndex(item => {
      return item.hasOwnProperty("oneOf");
    });
    oneOf = config.module.rules[oneOfIndex].oneOf;
    // Add the SVG and CSS loaders to the oneOf array
    const additions = [
      {
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
        use: ["raw-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
              themeImporter: {
                themePath: require.resolve("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark")
              },
              minify: true
            })
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    additions.forEach((item) => {
      oneOf.push(item);
    });
    const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
    const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
    // Modify cssRegex
    let loader;
    loader = oneOf.find(item => {
      if (item.test !== undefined)
        return item.test.toString() === cssRegex.toString();
    });
    loader.exclude = [cssModuleRegex, /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/];
    // Modify cssModuleRegex
    loader = oneOf.find(item => {
      if (item.test !== undefined)
        return item.test.toString() === cssModuleRegex.toString();
    });
    loader.exclude = [/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/];
    // Modify file-loader
    loader = oneOf.find(item => {
      if (item.loader !== undefined)
        return (
          item.loader.toString() === require.resolve("file-loader").toString()
        );
    });
    loader.exclude = [
      /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      /\.html$/,
      /\.json$/,
      /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
      /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/
    ];
    config.module.rules[oneOfIndex].oneOf = oneOf;
    return config;
  },
  devServer: function(configFunction) {
    // Return the replacement function for create-react-app to use to generate the Webpack
    // Development Server config. "configFunction" is the function that would normally have
    // been used to generate the Webpack Development server config - you can use it to create
    // a starting configuration to then modify instead of having to create a config from scratch.
    return function(proxy, allowedHost) {
      // Create the default config by calling configFunction with the proxy/allowedHost parameters
      const defaultConfig = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);
      return {
        ...defaultConfig,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        // Allow mounting react apps from a page served by the backend.
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
        },
      };
    };
  },
};
```

I am trying to load another react application as a microfront end using :
I ve tested the imported microfront end in a simple react app (container) and everything went well

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import {History} from 'history';

interface MicroFrontendProps {
  history?: History;
  name: string;
  host: string | undefined;
}

const MicroFrontend: React.FC<MicroFrontendProps> = ({history, name, host,}) => {

  const renderMicroFrontend = useCallback(() => {
    (window as any)[`render${name}`](`${name}-container`, history);
  }, [name, history]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptId = `micro-frontend-script-${name}`;

    if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
      renderMicroFrontend();
    } else {

      fetch(`${host}/asset-manifest.json`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(manifest => {
          const promises = Object.keys(manifest.files)
            .filter(key => key.endsWith('.js'))
            .reduce((sum, key) => {
              sum.push(
                new Promise(resolve => {
                  const path = `${host}${manifest.files[key]}`;
                  const script = document.createElement('script');

                  if (key === 'main.js') {
                    script.id = scriptId;
                  }

                  script.onload = () => {
                    resolve();
                  };

                  script.crossOrigin = '';
                  script.src = path;

                  document.body.after(script);
                }),
              );
              return sum;
            }, [] as any);

          Promise.allSettled(promises).then(() => {
            renderMicroFrontend();
          });
        });



    }

    return () => {
      (window as any)[`unmount${name}`](`${name}-container`);
    };
  }, [renderMicroFrontend, host, name]);

  return <main id={`${name}-container`} />;
};

export default MicroFrontend;
```

When I am importing the app, when I go to a link which loads it I am getting this error (the imported app is rendred but server shuts down) :

```
webpackHotDevClient.js:60 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:3000/sockjs-node' failed: 
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @ webpackHotDevClient.js:60
webpackHotDevClient.js:76 The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

Do you have any idea about this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this solved?